# jQuery/HTML Changing and saving plugin options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Shapeshift plugin](https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift/wiki/2.0-api-documentation)

The plugin has an option `gutterX: 'some value'`.

Also I'm initiating the plugin on my container as:

```
$(".container").shapeshift();
```

I can change the option as follows:

```
$(".container").shapeshift({
    gutterX:20
});
```

But how can I save this option's value in localstorage/cookie so that even if the browser is refreshed the value is retained.

Comment: You can use the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempgutterX = 20;

//GET
$(".container").shapeshift();
if(localStorage.getItem("gutterX"))
{
    $(".container").shapeshift({ gutterX: localStorage.getItem("gutterX") });
}
else
{
    $(".container").shapeshift({ gutterX: tempgutterX });

    //SET for later
    localStorage.setItem("gutterX", tempgutterX);
}
```

Using localstorage this will set from localstorage if it is stored already otherwise it will store for next time. 
You might also want to check the browser has localstorage support first.